# How to get safeAreaInsets in viewWillTransitionToSize (iPhone X)

Tags: ios, swift, iphone-x

I’m trying to update the `viewWillTransition(to size: with coordinator:)` method for iPhoneX.
But I can’t get the destinations of the safeAreaInsets values.
Please help!

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize,
        with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow { 
            let insets = window.safeAreaInsets
            contentFrame = CGRect(x:insets.left, y:insets.top,
                width:size.width - insets.left - insets.right,
                height:size.height - insets.top - insets.bottom)
        }
    } else {
        contentFrame = CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:size.width, height:size.height)
    }
    self.updateViews()
}
```

Comment: What does "I can’t get the destinations of the sefeAreaInsets values" mean? What's the problem? Why are you consulting the _window_? Your code makes no sense. What exactly are you trying to do, ultimately?

Comment: I want the value after rotation.
At this point it is before rotation

Comment: `viewWillTransitionToSize` is about only one thing: the size. The value of the size after rotation is `size`. What do you imagine that has to do with the safe area insets? And again I ask you: why do you need that information? What are you trying to do, ultimately? (I ask for the second time.)

Comment: To do the rotate animation routines.

Comment: Then perhaps you should say what they are. The fact that you need this information, in code, is a "bad smell". You weren't paying attention to the top and bottom layout guides before, so why do you care about the safe area insets now? I ask you again: _What's the problem?_ You see, this is an x-y question. Instead of asking about what you _really_ want to know, you have made a _false assumption_ and now you're upset that it isn't working. It isn't _going_ to work; it's false. You need to step back and ask about your _real_ problem.

Comment: In my code, there is a rotation routine in the `viewWillTransition(to:with:)` in the root view controller.
Then it locates each views with `animateWithDuration(:animations:completion:)` methods. It needs destination CGRects.
In other than iphoneX, There was no problem if only fit to screen-size was done. But in the case of iphonex, It also needs  safeAreaInsets of the device.

This may be a bad smell code as you say, Please let me know if you know the right way.

Comment: Okay but you are still not answering the question. Why to you need safe area insets in this one case? And if you do, why don't you just _constrain_ to the safe area? That's what it's for. (Also you should be using the transition coordinator, not calling `animateWithDuration`. That's what the transition coordinator is for!)

Comment: @matt, I meet similar issue - I have 2 controllers, both have safeArea guide set. When one is visible - everything is ok, I don't need to take care of insets. However if one is presented via "presentViewController" as popup - background one receives notification where layoutSubviews doesn't consider safeArea. In other words, if 2 controllers open, after rotation, background one is incorrectly layouted

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I got the valid solution at Stackoverflow Japan.

It's just getting the insets in the `UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator.animate(alongsideTransition:completion:)` closure like below:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { (context) in
        ...

        let insets = ...safeAreaInsets

        ...
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also have this issue. After experimenting and I found a nice workaround without waiting for transition to finish.

1. have a view (let's call it `SizeListenerView`) that anchor to the safe area, so that we only need to listen to this view's size change

In `SizeListenerView`

```
    override var bounds: CGRect {
        didSet {
            // now you can access the bounds here
        }
    }
```