# Why is the logic of retrieving SafeAreaInsets in `viewWillTransitionToSize` slightly wrong?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, screen-rotation, safearealayoutguide

I'm exploring if the landscape "Safe Area insets" can be presicely known in `viewWillTransitionToSize` when rotating from Portrait to Landscape.

I've seen this SO answer, its code is rather a pseudocode: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46581783/2567725

On my iPhone XR insets are `{48, 0, 34, 0}` for portrait and `{0, 48, 21, 48}` for Landscape.
Like this:
[image]

When rotating a device - from Portrait to Landscape - I log the "future" insets in `animateAlongsideTransition`, and they are correct.
The question is, why those correct values are retrieved from `FromViewControllerKey`, not from `ToViewControllerKey`:

```
- (void)logSafeAreaInsets:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext>)context
{
    UIInputViewController* vcFrom = [context viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
    UIEdgeInsets iiFrom = vcFrom.view.safeAreaInsets;
    UIInputViewController* vcTo = [context viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];
    UIEdgeInsets iiTo = vcTo.view.safeAreaInsets;
    NSLog(@"TADAM from=%@ to=%@", NSStringFromUIEdgeInsets(iiFrom), NSStringFromUIEdgeInsets(iiTo));
}

- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
    
    [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext>  _Nonnull context) {
        
        [self logSafeAreaInsets:context];
        
    } completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext>  _Nonnull context) {
            
    }];
}
```

And for `ToViewControllerKey` they are `{0, 0, 0, 0}` !
The logs look like this:

```
TADAM from={0, 48, 21, 48} to={0, 0, 0, 0}
```

As I understand, `ToViewControllerKey` is a Landscape VC (after rotation), and `FromViewControllerKey` is a Portrait VC (before rotation).

So I can get what I want `UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext`, but its logic seems wrong:

1. Why real Landscape insets are retrieved from `FromVC`, not from `ToVC` ?
2. Why insets for `ToVC` are zero in `animateAlongsideTransition`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the logic isn't "slightly wrong", it's just undocumented.
As it turned out, `vcTo` is `nil` in my code. So insets are `zero`.
`vcTo` is nil because screen rotation animation is done with only one `VC`, unlike e.g. transitioning animation when pushing/presenting a new `VC`.

I guess that `vcFrom` has already `Landscape` insets in `animateAlongsideTransition` because of difference btw the `model layer tree` and the `presentation layer tree` - while I don't know yet how to check this assumption.